# convert time vector into decimal day

Tags: r, time-series

I have a vector of dates:

```
Date = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00"), 
           to=as.POSIXct("2011-12-31 23:00"), length=8760)
```

It is possible to convert this into decimal time, something along the lines of:

```
DecDay = seq(1,366,length = 8760)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `as.numeric(julian(Date, Date[1]))`.