# Date objects in decimals spanning multiple leap years

Tags: r, lubridate

I would like to figure out a way to convert a day into a decimal where 0 is January 1 and December 31 is 1. No time here just days. I looked for a few solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188933/convert-time-vector-into-decimal-day) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/169870.html) but neither of those solution seem to fit my problem. I also had hopes for the `date_decimal` function in `lubridate`. I have figured out a solution which involves converting the `Date` into a number, merging a dataframe that accounts for leaps years then divides the number by the total number of days in the year.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

 df <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2003/2/10"), as.Date("2007/2/10"), "years"),
       var=seq(1,5, by=1))
```

`lubridate` function attempt:

```
 date_decimal(df$Date)
```

Leap year dataframe

```
 maxdaydf<-data.frame(Year=seq(2003,2007,by=1),   maxdays=c(365,366,365,365,365))
```

A `dplyr` pipe to generate the `daydecimal`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Year=year(Date), daynum=yday(Date)) %>%
  full_join(maxdaydf, by=c("Year")) %>%
  mutate(daydecimal=daynum/maxdays)
```

But as I said this is clunky and involves a 2nd dataframe which is never ideal. Any suggestions on how I can convert some Dates into decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `date_decimal()` you could use `decimal_date()`

```
decimal_date(df$Date)
[1] 2003.110 2004.109 2005.110 2006.110 2007.110
```

Or you can use :

```
yday(df$Date)/yday(ISOdate(year(df$Date), 12,31))
[1] 0.1123288 0.1120219 0.1123288 0.1123288 0.1123288
```

Comment: Should I just delete this question? Seems a little dumb now :)